# AppCompat V7 - Cannot customize material Theme

Tags: android, xml, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I added the **AppCompat V7** library to add some **Material Design** elements to the UX of an app that has to support **older devices** (`android:minSdkVersion="16"`)

I was able to add the `Theme.AppCompat.Light` theme to my app and **even did some customizations** of the action bar with `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse`. The **problem** comes when I try to do the simplest changes to the main theme, like changing colors as follow:

```xtml
    <style name="Theme.AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

I keep getting this **error**: `error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.`.

I already checked that the **build targets** for the project and AppCompat are the same, but with **no luck**.

I think it has something to do with refering to the resources from the library, because when I **copy** the `themes.xml` file to my project, **it works**.

Is that the way **I'm supposed to do it?** Wasn't the library there to contain all the resources I need so I wouldn't have to copy them manually?

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a sample project demonstrating customizing `colorPrimary` and `colorPrimaryDark`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppCompat/ActionBarColor It should be importable directly into Android Studio. If you import it into Eclipse, you will need to properly attach the `appcompat-v7` library project.

Comment: AppCompat not yet added to your project, check your gradle.build, is there something like 'compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+' in the dependencies

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you fro responding. I have attached 'appcompat-v7' to my app succesfully, that's how I'm able to use the 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'. As I said, the problem is that I cannot customize it...

Comment: @Xingchen I'm using Eclipse, but appcompat-v7 seems to be working.

Comment: @Selvin I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: I am also using appcompat-v7 for material theme, works fine. If appcompat-v7 is imported as library properly, then it should not give 'No resource found' error

Comment: "As I said, the problem is that I cannot customize it" -- and as *I* said, the sample app demonstrates customizing it.

Comment: @Xingchen As far as I know it's properly imported, it gives no problem when I use <style name="Theme.AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"> . Is there something I should do other than matching build targets and adding the library?

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm trying to customize it the same way as in the example, I still don't see the difference.

Comment: It sounds weird if you have done properly! I suppose you have had definition of colorPrimary in color.xml file. And also why you have same color for both of colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark

Comment: @buzoherbert have you found out the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Build targets for your project and AppCompat-v7 need to be both level 21.